# Comparing Range of DateTimes in a Loop

Tags: c#, loops, datetime

I have a start date and an end date as well as a list of specific dates (holidays).
From the start date to the end date, first I determine if there are any weekends, if there are, I need to determine how many days are weekends and add the number of days to the end date, then determine if any of those dates fall in the list of dates in the holiday list.  Again, if a date is in the holiday list, I have to take that number of days, add it to the end and run through the loop again.

For Example.  Initial Date Range is 11/20/2017 to 11/24/2017.  The first check for weekends would return 0, then I check for holidays, that would return 2 (the 23rd and 24th), I would then need to adjust the dates so my new range is from 11/20 to 11/26, to which I have to loop through weekends again and will find 2 days are in the weekend.  Etc.  The below code I cheated because I know that there are never more than 2 holidays back to back, but its very cumbersome code.

Also, please consider if the weekends come first, followed by holidays once you adjust for the initial weekend.

I never have an issue with just weekends, it is only for holidays that I am given the wrong value. The code below works fine, I am just looking to see suggestions as to how it can be improved.  I have tried for loops, while loops, and this is the only scenario that seems to work.  Thanks for your help.

```
   public static int weekends(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<DateTime> holidays, Boolean leftSpace)
    {
        int days = 0;

        DateTime tempstart = start;
        TimeSpan startEnd = end - start;
        int currentDays = startEnd.Days;
        for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            int dw = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
            if (dw == 0 || dw == 6)
            {
                days++;
            }

        }

        if (!leftSpace)
        {
            end = end.AddDays(days);
            if (end.DayOfWeek == 0)
            {
                end = end.AddDays(1);
                days++;
            }
            else if ((int)end.DayOfWeek == 6)
            {
                end = end.AddDays(2);
                days = days + 2;
            }
            Boolean holidayExist = false;
            int holidayCount = 0;
            foreach (DateTime holiday in holidays.Where(r => r.Date >= start.Date && r.Date <= end.Date))
            {
                days++;
                holidayCount++;
                holidayExist = true;
            }
            if (holidayExist)
            {
                DateTime tempend = end;
                end = end.AddDays(holidayCount);
                int newWeekend = 0;
                for (DateTime date = tempend; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
                {
                    int dw = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
                    if (dw == 0 || dw == 6)
                    {
                        days++;
                        newWeekend++;
                    }

                }
                holidayExist = false;
                holidayCount = 0;
                DateTime holidayEnd = end.AddDays(newWeekend);
                foreach (DateTime holiday in holidays.Where(r => r.Date >= end.Date && r.Date <= holidayEnd.Date))
                {
                    days++;
                    holidayCount++;
                    holidayExist = true;
                }
                if (holidayExist)
                {
                    tempend = end;
                    end = end.AddDays(holidayCount);
                    for (DateTime date = tempend; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        int dw = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
                        if (dw == 0 || dw == 6)
                        {
                            days++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return days;
    }
```

Comment: Would suggest you take this to code review

Comment: @BugFinder Since this code does not work as intended, I'd advice against it. Please take a look at [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @mast - but he said it worked fine!

Comment: @BugFinder - he is actually saying both :) - ``I never have an issue with just weekends...`` and ``The code below works fine...``

Comment: @BugFinder "it is only for holidays that I am given the **wrong** value." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yes, this code works correctly, I am just looking for a better way to write the function so I am not running so many loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this for performance but it works. List holidays is a list of dates that are being skipped as they are holidays.

```
public static int weekends(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        int days = 0;

        DateTime tempEnd = end;
        TimeSpan startEnd = end - start;
        int currentDays = startEnd.Days;

            int exclusionDays = 0;
            int exclWEOld = 0;
            int exclHDOld = 0;
            while (currentDays >= 0)
            {
                int excHolidayTest = exclHolidays(start, tempEnd, holidays);
                int excDayTest = exclDays(start, tempEnd);
                if (exclusionDays == (excDayTest+ excHolidayTest))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    exclusionDays = excDayTest + excHolidayTest;
                    if (exclWEOld == 0 && exclHDOld == 0)
                    {
                        tempEnd = tempEnd.AddDays((excDayTest + excHolidayTest));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempEnd = tempEnd.AddDays((excDayTest - exclWEOld));
                        tempEnd = tempEnd.AddDays((excHolidayTest - exclHDOld));
                    }
                    exclWEOld = excDayTest;
                    exclHDOld = excHolidayTest;

                }
                days = excDayTest + excHolidayTest;
                currentDays--;
            }



        return days;
    }
    public static int exclDays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        int exclusionDays = 0;
        for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            int dw = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
            if (dw == 0 || dw == 6)
            {
                exclusionDays++;
            }

        }
        return exclusionDays;
    }
    public static int exclHolidays(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        int exclusionHolidays = 0;

        foreach (DateTime holiday in holidays.Where(r => r.Date >= start.Date && r.Date <= end.Date))
        {
            exclusionHolidays++;
        }

        return exclusionHolidays;
    }
```